# Rails 3: How do I delay content submission so users can't spam rapidly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spam-prevention

For instance, if a user submits a post, there should be a delay period of maybe 10 minutes in which he or she cannot submit another post.

Could someone point me to a good gem/tutorial/method? For reference, I'm on Rails 3.

Comment: lol even reddit does this, don't know why you're complaining

Comment: Flood checks are so annoying.  I shouldn't be punished because I actually know how to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tracking by user, you can keep a column called `last_active` which is a datetime field, and update it when the user submits the form. (Assuming there aren't a lot of form,s, then maybe think about giving these timestamps their own model).

Then, just perform date math to see if ten minutes has gone by.

`user.last_active + 10.minutes > Time.now ? "User can post" : "User cannot post"`

**Note:** Not in front of a console, that might be `10.minute`

Then your form logic:

```
def form_stuff
  //Form Logic
  @user.last_active = Time.now
end
```

Comment: `10.minutes` should be correct. The plural is the default for these helpers. This is the opposite of SQL `INTERVAL` directives.

Comment: thanks! by the way, if i wanted to add a datetime field to a model, what is the syntax? is it t.datetime :last_active?

Comment: That it is, assuming t is the variable you set for the create_table statement

Comment: Convention has it that `datetime` fields end in `_at`, so `last_active_at` might be a better column name.